# Inline-Block error when using batik on NVD3 svg

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js, batik

I'm trying to use Batik Rasterizer with an NVD3 chart but it's giving me the following error

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar samples/discreteBar.svg
Enclosed Exception:
file:/c:/batik-1.7/samples/nv.d3.css:
Invalid CSS document.
The "inline-block" identifier is not a valid value for the "display" property.
```

I'm using NVD3's default css file. The only modification I made was to add some header properties to the svg file. Stuff like "DOCTYPE" and "xml-stylesheet". Without those, batik didn't even attempt to build.

This is the NVD3 chart i'm trying to rasterize.
http://nvd3.org/ghpages/discreteBar.html

This is the svg source (for some reason, its not appearing properly in my chrome browser but it work in IE, FF and safari. )
[The SVG Code](http://sonarinformatique.com/tempo/discreteBar.svg)

This is the half finished png file it manages to generate
[Generated PNG file](http://sonarinformatique.com/tempo/discreteBar.png)

This is the css file
[NV.D3.css](http://sonarinformatique.com/tempo/nv.d3.css)

This is the full exception error
[Full Exception](http://sonarinformatique.com/tempo/ExceptionError.txt)

Is NVD3 incompatible with Batik, is it a batik build settings issue, is NVD3 using non standard css?  Has anyone manage to use Batik on NVD3 charts before?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline-block was invented [after the SVG 1.1 specification was written](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#DisplayProperty).

It seems that Batik does not support this so you'd have to change the `NV.D3.css` file to use one of the values from SVG 1.1

Try swapping `inline-block` for either `inline` or `block` and see if it makes any difference and which one you'd rather have.

Answer (score 0):

Converted nvd3 css file which takes care of the transcoding issue while using Batik -

```
/* Modified nvd3 css file for Batik transcoding support */
.nvd3 .nv-axis {
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-opacity: .75;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis path.domain {
    stroke-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-x path.domain {
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #e5e5e5;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis .zero line,
    /*this selector may not be necessary*/ .nvd3 .nv-axis line.zero {
    stroke-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nvd3 .x  .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text,
.nvd3 .x2 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text,
.nvd3 .x3 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text {
    text-anchor: middle;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-disabled {
    opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars rect {
    fill-opacity: .75;

    transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars rect.hover {
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars .hover rect {
    fill: lightblue;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars text {
    fill: rgb(0,0,0);
    fill-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars .hover text {
    fill: rgb(0,0,0);
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-multibar .nv-groups rect,
.nvd3 .nv-multibarHorizontal .nv-groups rect,
.nvd3 .nv-discretebar .nv-groups rect {
    stroke-opacity: 0;

    transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3 .nv-multibar .nv-groups rect:hover,
.nvd3 .nv-multibarHorizontal .nv-groups rect:hover,
.nvd3 .nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks rect:hover,
.nvd3 .nv-discretebar .nv-groups rect:hover {
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-discretebar .nv-groups text,
.nvd3 .nv-multibarHorizontal .nv-groups text {
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: rgb(0,0,0);
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke: rgb(0,0,0);
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

/* boxplot CSS */
.nvd3 .nv-boxplot circle {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

.nvd3 .nv-boxplot circle:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-boxplot rect:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 line.nv-boxplot-median {
  stroke: black;
}

.nv-boxplot-tick:hover {
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
/* bullet */
.nvd3.nv-bullet { font: 10px sans-serif; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-measure { fill-opacity: .8; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-measure:hover { fill-opacity: 1; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-marker { stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-markerTriangle { stroke: #000; fill: #fff; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-markerLine { stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-tick line { stroke: #666; stroke-width: .5px; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range.nv-s0 { fill: #eee; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range.nv-s1 { fill: #ddd; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range.nv-s2 { fill: #ccc; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-title { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-subtitle { fill: #999; }

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range {
    fill: #bababa;
    fill-opacity: .4;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range:hover {
    fill-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick {
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.hover {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.positive rect {
    stroke: #2ca02c;
    fill: #2ca02c;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.negative rect {
    stroke: #d62728;
    fill: #d62728;
}

.with-transitions .nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick {
    transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks line {
    stroke: #333;
}

.nv-force-node {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.nv-force-link {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .6;
}

.nv-force-node text {
    stroke-width: 0px;
}

.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-disabled rect {
    /*fill-opacity: 0;*/
}

.nvd3 .nv-check-box .nv-box {
    fill-opacity:0;
    stroke-width:2;
}

.nvd3 .nv-check-box .nv-check {
    fill-opacity:0;
    stroke-width:4;
}

.nvd3 .nv-series.nv-disabled .nv-check-box .nv-check {
    fill-opacity:0;
    stroke-opacity:0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-controlsWrap .nv-legend .nv-check-box .nv-check {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* line plus bar */
.nvd3.nv-linePlusBar .nv-bar rect {
    fill-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3.nv-linePlusBar .nv-bar rect:hover {
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
.nvd3 .nv-groups path.nv-line {
    fill: none;
}

.nvd3 .nv-groups path.nv-area {
    stroke: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-line .nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-scatter.nv-single-point .nv-groups .nv-point {
    fill-opacity: .5 !important;
    stroke-opacity: .5 !important;
}


.with-transitions .nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point {
    transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point.hover,
.nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point.hover {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    fill-opacity: .95 !important;
    stroke-opacity: .95 !important;
}


.nvd3 .nv-point-paths path {
    stroke: #aaa;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
    fill: #eee;
    fill-opacity: 0;
}


.nvd3 .nv-indexLine {
    cursor: auto;
}

/********************
 * SVG CSS
 */

/********************
  Default CSS for an svg element nvd3 used
*/
svg.nvd3-svg {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

/********************
  Box shadow and border radius styling
*/
.nvtooltip.with-3d-shadow, .with-3d-shadow .nvtooltip {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.nvd3 text {
    font: normal 12px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nvd3 .title {
    font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nvd3 .nv-background {
    fill: white;
    fill-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-noData {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/**********
*  Brush
*/

.nv-brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: .125;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nv-brush .resize path {
    fill: #eee;
    stroke: #666;
}


/**********
*  Legend
*/

.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-series {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-disabled circle {
    fill-opacity: 0;
}

/* focus */
.nvd3 .nv-brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: 0 !important;
}

.nvd3 .nv-brushBackground rect {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: .4;
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .7;
}

/**********
*  Print
*/

@media print {
    .nvd3 text {
        stroke-width: 0;
        fill-opacity: 1;
    }
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick {
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.hover {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.positive {
    stroke: #2ca02c;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.negative {
    stroke: #d62728;
}


.nvd3 .background path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #EEE;
    stroke-opacity: .4;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .foreground path {
    fill: none;
    stroke-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3 .nv-parallelCoordinates-brush .extent {
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .6;
    stroke: gray;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .nv-parallelCoordinates .hover  {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}


.nvd3 .missingValuesline line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie path {
    stroke-opacity: 0;
    transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-pie-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    fill: rgb(19, 196, 249);
    fill-opacity:0.59;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-slice text {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie path {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie path {
    fill-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .hover path {
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-label {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-label rect {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

/* scatter */
.nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point.hover {
    stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.nvd3 .nv-scatter .nv-point.hover {
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nv-noninteractive {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nv-distx, .nv-disty {
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* sparkline */
.nvd3.nv-sparkline path {
    fill: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus g.nv-hoverValue {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-hoverValue line {
    stroke: #333;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus,
.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus g {
    pointer-events: all;
}

.nvd3 .nv-hoverArea {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-xValue,
.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-yValue {
    stroke-width: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-yValue {
    stroke: #f66;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-maxValue {
    stroke: #2ca02c;
    fill: #2ca02c;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-minValue {
    stroke: #d62728;
    fill: #d62728;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-currentValue {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
/* stacked area */
.nvd3.nv-stackedarea path.nv-area {
    fill-opacity: .7;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
    transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-stackedarea path.nv-area.hover {
    fill-opacity: .9;
}


.nvd3.nv-stackedarea .nv-groups .nv-point {
    stroke-opacity: 0;
    fill-opacity: 0;
}

.nvtooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    color-opacity: 1.0;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;

    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    pointer-events: none;

    white-space: nowrap;

    -webkit-user-select: none;

       -moz-user-select: none;

        -ms-user-select: none;

            user-select: none;
}

.nvtooltip {
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/*Give tooltips that old fade in transition by
    putting a "with-transitions" class on the container div.
*/
.nvtooltip.with-transitions, .with-transitions .nvtooltip {
    transition: opacity 50ms linear;

    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.nvtooltip.x-nvtooltip,
.nvtooltip.y-nvtooltip {
    padding: 8px;
}

.nvtooltip h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: rgba(247,247,247,0.75);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    color-opacity: 1.0;
    text-align: center;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;

    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.nvtooltip p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nvtooltip span {
    display: inline;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.nvtooltip table {
    margin: 6px;
    border-spacing:0;
}


.nvtooltip table td {
    padding: 2px 9px 2px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nvtooltip table td.key {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.nvtooltip table td.key.total {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nvtooltip table td.value {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nvtooltip table td.percent {
    color: darkgray;
}

.nvtooltip table tr.highlight td {
    padding: 1px 9px 1px 0;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.nvtooltip .footer {
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nvtooltip-pending-removal {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: none;
}


/****
Interactive Layer
*/
.nvd3 .nv-interactiveGuideLine {
    pointer-events:none;
}

.nvd3 line.nv-guideline {
    stroke: #ccc;
}
```